# How to declare callback like Parse does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

Usually, I declare a function with success and fail callbacks as follow

```
function yoyoyo(param, successCallback, failCallback) {
  // do something with param
  // ...
  if (success) {
    successCallback('success');
  } else {
    failCallback('fail');
  }
}
```

then I will use it like this

```
yoyoyo('abc', function(success) {
  console.log(success);
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);  
});
```

**BUT**, when I look into Parse Javascript Guide, they guide me to use the function like this (i.e. merge success and fail callbacks in one object?)

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.get("xWMyZ4YEGZ", {
  success: function(gameScore) {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

**How can I declare my function with success and fail callbacks like parse does?**

Comment: consider returning a promise instead of handling these callbacks via arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would just change your function to accept a callbacks arg (call it whatever you want) and then access the handlers off that object:

```
function yoyoyo(param, callbacks) {
  // do something with param
  // ...
  if (success) {
    callbacks.success('success');
  } else {
    callbacks.error('fail');
  }
}
```

then you would call it with:

```
yoyoyo('abc', {
    success: function(status) { 
    },
    error: function(status) {
    }
});
```

Note though, that your code should check to ensure that the object passed in has both of the methods before attempting to call them.

Answer (score 2):

That method is accepting a object that contains two function pointers. So it's a bit like creating an object thus:

```
var parameters = {success:function() {}, error:function(){}};
```

You can simply change your method thus:

```
function yoyoyo(param, callbacks) {
   //Add some error checking to check the callbacks is in the right state      
   if (typeof callbacks.success != "undefined" && typeof callbacks.error!= "undefined")
   {

       // do something with param
       // ...
       if (success) {
          callbacks.success('success');
       } else {
          callbacks.error('fail');
       }
  }
  else {
     throw "callbacks must contain a success and error method";
  }
}
```

then call it:

```
.yoyoto(param, {success:function() {}, error:function(){}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you want is an argument that is an object with `success` and `error` functions as attributes

You can declare the function like so

```
function (param, callbacks) {
  // do something with param
  // ...
  if (success) {
    if(callbacks && callbacks.success) callbacks.success('success');
  } else {
    if(callbacks && callbacks.fail) callbacks.fail('fail');
  }
}
```

As a side note since I see you've tagged `node.js`, I would also recommend you look at using a single [error-first callback](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/), which keeps your functions/apis simple and also follows a rather standard node convention.